# How to comment out a string in xml file in shell

Tags: xml, linux, shell, unix, sed

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE sailpoint PUBLIC 'sailpoint.dtd' 'sailpoint.dtd'>
<sailpoint>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Application/CARD/CommonCardFiles/COF Imaging Applications Custom Object.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Configuration/COF - Singlenter code heree Entitlement Application Custom Object.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Rule/COF Related Application Library.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Form/COF LCM CBT Form.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Workflow/COF Identity Refresh Bypass.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Configuration/COF Unstable Roles Config.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Application/CARD/CommonCardFiles/COF Salesforce Common Correlation Rule.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Rule/COF Single SOD Violation Detection Rule.xml'/>
<ImportAction name='include' value='custom/Configuration/COF APPLICATION DEPENDENCY 
</sailpoint>*
```

On above mention code i am trying to comment out all the line with pattern custom/Application in it

sed command i use that is not working

```
sed '/<custom&Application>/s/\(.*\)/<--\1-->/' est.xml > new.xml
```

Comment: Do you want to comment the tag containing `value='custom/Application`?

Comment: Yes value='custom/Application* every this pattern occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

`sed -e '/custom\/Application/s/\(^.*$\)/<!--\1-->/' est.xml > new.xml`

Answer (score 2):

You can match the complete lines with `custom` and `Applicatioin` in it.
Use `&` for the matched string.

```
sed 's/.*custom.*Application.*/<!--&-->/' est.xml > new.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

XML data should be parsed with an XML parser.

You can *delete* those tags with [xmlstarlet](/questions/tagged/xmlstarlet)

```
xmlstarlet ed -d '//ImportAction[contains(@value,"custom/Application")]' file.xml
```

I'm not sure how to comment them.

Comment: Actually this is better than the `sed` solutions commenting a line. xml elements are usually not bound to a line, the `sed` solutions can break things in the middle of an element.