# Add line above a particular XML tag and one line below of the ending XML tag

Tags: python, xml, shell

I have a file with content as below:

```
<root>
    <appender name="abc">
     some lines
    </appender>
    <appender name="def">
      some lines
    </appender>
    <appender name="qaz">
      some lines
    </appender>
</root>
```

I want to comment below:

```
  <!--
    <appender name="def">
      some lines
    </appender>-->
```

What is did is

```
sed -i '/<appender name="def"/s/^/<--/;/<\/appender>/s/$/-->/' file.xml
```

This adds `<!--` on top of `<appender name="def">` but `-->` is added on all lines where `</appender>` is present. I want to add `-->` only on the `</appender>` which get search after first match is done.

Output should be as below:

```
<root>
    <appender name="abc">
     some lines
    </appender>
<!--
    <appender name="def">
      some lines
    </appender>-->
    <appender name="qaz">
      some lines
    </appender>
</root>
```

I tried searching lots for similar problem but couldn't find it.

Comment: Deleting an element is easy with an XML-aware command line tool such as xmlstarlet. Commenting out is harder. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671491/how-to-comment-out-a-string-in-xml-file-in-shell.

Answer (score 0):

Save the following to `process.awk`

```
/<appender name="def">/ {
        show = 1
        print "<!--"
}

/<\/appender>/ {
        if( show == 1 )
        {
                $0 = $0 "-->"
                show = 0
        }
}

{
        print
}
```

and use

```
awk -f process.awk file.xml
```

Explanation:

1. Mark it if desired pattern appears, and print the comment marker.
2. If the ending pattern appears, append the closing comment.
3. Print the modified line.

For the purpose of online display, the awk script is written in a separate file. If you prefer, you can easily transform it into inline version.

Answer (score 0):

dibery's answer looks great but since you tagged python as well I will provide a simple script that does your job.

```
with open("file.xml", "r") as r:
    lines = r.readlines()

gotcha = False                 # Just a flag to know if we catched the field
with open("file.xml", "w") as w:
    for k in range(len(lines)):
        if '<appender name="def">' in lines[k]:
            w.write("<!--\n") 
            gotcha = True      # We got it!
        w.write(lines[k])
        if '</appender>' in lines[k] and gotcha:
            w.write('-->\n')
            gotcha = False     # We have done our job, this avoids commenting every other '</appender>' field
```

Output

```
<root>
    <appender name="abc">
     some lines
    </appender>
<!--
    <appender name="def">
      some lines
    </appender>
-->
    <appender name="qaz">
      some lines
    </appender>
</root>
```

Comment: will this take care of closing the file descriptor. i have run the script continuously in interval, so there should not be any FD leaks.

Comment: Yes, It will only close the file descriptor of <appender name="def">. All the other ones are left unchanged